# Find and replace assembly with regex in visual studio

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2010

We have a solution with over 25 projects, each one with it's own `AssemblyInfo` I am trying to increment all of the assembly numbers to increase one major version for our next release.

My regex skills are minimal but essentially I want to find:

```
<Assembly: AssemblyVersion("x.x.x.x")>
```

Where `x` in regex terms will be `\d`/a number. Looking [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) I thought I could use:

```
{AssemblyVersion("[\d].[\d].[\d].[\d]")}
```

Which didn't work, it doesn't like the open brackets. My question is essentially broken down into two stages:

1. What regex string will I use to find the example?
2. Is it possible to replace the first digit with the digit + 1 using regex? (I suspect I am being a bit optimisitic) if so what will the regex string be in this situation?

This is in source control, so I wouldn't like to modify the files directly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean a `\d/a` number?

Comment: I'm not sure if this would help, but you could treat your `Assembly Version` release like an IP Address.  They are often used to find and modify frequently.  One of those RegEx may work.

Comment: @RyanGates In regex terms it's `\d` as far as I am aware. If my awareness is a bit off, it's a number! :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: this is using the Visual Studio regex find and replace.

I don't think you can add one while doing a regex replace.  However, you could substitute a literal number.  For example, you could use a regex that replaces the first digit `1` with a `99`:

`AssemblyVersion("1.0.2121.0")` --> `AssemblyVersion("99.0.2121.0")`

Here is the regex I used for the Visual Studio Search and replace:

```
Search Regex:  AssemblyVersion[(]["]([0-9]+)([.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+)["][)]
Replace Regex: AssemblyVersion("99${2}")
```

The search regex escapes all special characters `(.")` by wrapping them in square brackets. Then it uses parenthesis to split the version number into two groups. The first group is the first set of digits. The second group is the last three sets of digits.

For example, `AssemblyVersion("1.0.2121.0")` is grouped like this (using braces for groupings):
`AssemblyVersion("{1}{.0.2121.0}")`. So group 1 is `1`, and group 2 is `.0.2121.0`.

The replace regex `AssemblyVersion("99${2}")`uses a literal and group 2 from the search regex to build the replacement string.  The `${2}` means use the text from group 2. The rest of the string is the literal.

Comment: This looks perfect :) I am changing from doing this manuall to getting an automated build to increment version numbers so I don't have to do this, but this will work for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use C# to find your text then I think this is the regex you will need - I have wrapped it up in a verbatim string and escaped the double quotes.

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"<Assembly: AssemblyVersion\(""\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+""\)>");
```

If you want to pick elements to manipulate the string into a new string then add some brackets like so:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"<Assembly: AssemblyVersion\(""(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)""\)>");
```

You can then access the numbers individually to create a new string using the regex groups:

```
Match match = regex.Match(your_search_text);
if (match.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[2].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[3].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[4].Value);
}
```

Comment: I think it's a bit beyond find and replace. When it comes to searching through many files to find a text pattern I would fire up Powershell as this is really the ideal task for a command line.